# Is my proof correct? (prequel to inverse matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

This question comes from a section before inverse matrices are introduced.

---

Suppose $AD=I_m$. Show that for any **b** in $R^m$, the equation $A$**x**$=$**b** has a solution. [*Hint:* Think about the equation $AD$**b**$=$**b**] Explain why $A$ cannot have more rows than columns.

---

My attempt:

Let **b** be any element of $R^m$, and define **x** as follows:

**x**$=D$**b**

Left multiply both sides by $A$

$A$**x**$=A(D$**b**$)$

$A$**x**$=I_m $**b**

$A$**x**$=$**b**

We have mapped every **b** in $R^m$ to some **x** in **x**$=D$**b**, so in $A$**x**=**b** we just map back from some **x** to any **b** in $R^m$

$A$ cannot have more rows than columns because if it did, the row echelon form of $A$ would necessarily have at least one row of zeroes, which would restrict **b** to having at least one $0$ entry.

IS my proof correct? Is there a better proof or a proof that uses the hint given?

Comment: Correct, the point is that the matrix $A$ is invertible and $D=A^{-1}$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Yes, though this question came from before the idea of an inverse matrix was defined. I am a little concerned that my proof doesn't use the hint though

Comment: You do use the hint, by taking $x=Db$, you get $$Ax=ADb=b.$$

Comment: @Mathematician42 Right, I just asked my professor and I realized I did it a little backwards, you can just start with $b=b \implies (AD)b=b \implies A(Db)=b \implies Ax=b$